# Edit Drupal Form in "popup" just like it is done in Drupal Views Edit form

Tags: views, 7, datetime, javascript

I am making replica of **views** module. We when navigate to view in admin/list/structure, we **add new view**. Here we type name of our view and content type. After clicking "**save and continue**", it is redirected to **view edit page**.

On the top, there is, 
***Title
title:None***
And when we click on "None", a popup box will appear to edit title of the view and replaces "None" with the title given by us.

I need to have this **edit in popup functionality**. Can anyone please help doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the ctools modal functionality.
Without further digging into that - because I think the following tutorial is comprehensive, easy to understand and complete - here is a link that will help you: https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/insert-form-pop-modal-ctools-and-drupal-7

Some important things you should not forget:

1. Add the ctools module as dependency.
2. Add the callback to the menu.
3. Include the ctools js files on the page where the link to the title popup is.

ctools modal helped me a lot! Give it a try!